# Retrieve Contact thumbnail image from People App in Windows 8 Metro

Tags: javascript, windows, contacts, thumbnails, microsoft-metro

I use below code to retrieve contact name from People's App in my Metro App:

```
    function selectContact() {

    var picker = Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
    picker.commitButtonText = "Select";
    picker.selectionMode = Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactSelectionMode.contacts;
            picker.pickMultipleContactsAsync().done(function (contacts) {
        if(contacts.length>0){
            var j =document.getElementById("contactlist");
            contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
                j.innerHTML += contact.name + "<br>";
            });
}
```

Now, I need to retrieve contact thumbnail image and add it to my application. There is a getThumbnailAsync() method for contacts but I'm not sure how to use it... I used below code but thumbnail.size is always zero:

```
    contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
        contact.getThumbnailAsync().done(function (thumbnail) {
            if (thumbnail.size > 0) {
                var imageBlob = window.URL.createObjectURL(thumbnail,false);
                document.getElementById("contactlist").innerHTML += "<img id=" + i + " /><br>";
                document.getElementById(i).src = imageBlob;
                i++;
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay to me. I would check whether your user account allows apps to use your image. You can specify this in the PC settings:

[image]

It might just be that you don't allow it and thus the method always returns 0 length for the image.

**EDIT:** sorry, I just re-read your question and saw you are talking about the People app. Sorry, I'm not sure but I will leave this answer here in case anyone else stumbles upon this when trying to get to the account picture of the logged in user.